# How to infer relationships and cardinality from a database when generating code from the tables?

Tags: c#, database-design, code-generation, sql-server-2012, cardinality

I'm working on generating code (models) from my database. I'm not sure how to, if possible, setup my database to create a relationship including cardinality. Is this something that can be done, or am I stuck with simply generating models that match a table without relationships or cardinality because I did a data-first design?

Oh, and in case I'm using the incorrect term, cardinality is the type of relationship (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many). That way my models will generate with a reference to another model, or to an `ICollection<T>` of models.

For example:

```
public class OrderInformation
{
     public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }

     public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

     public virtual BillingInformation BillingInfo { get; set; }

     public virtual Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<ItemInformation> ShoppingCart { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Most of my database generation was inside T4 templates. You can leverage Sql Management Objects since relations are preserved. I also wrote a [MultiMapper for Dapper](https://gist.github.com/Romoku/5310100) which can handle Many-to-Many relationships.

Comment: @TimB: No, I'm not using Entity Framework... but even if I were, wouldn't the database setup have to be the same in order for EF to generate models correctly?

Comment: I asked because other tooling might be able to pull more information from the database than EF does. As far as I know, there is nothing you can do to change how EF generates code.